# Velocity assignment of one variable to another

Tags: java, velocity

I'm using Velocity through a Java application.  The velocity in question looks like this:

```
#if( $name1 != "" )
    #set($line11 = "<CharStyle:-bold black> ${name1}<CharStyle:>")
#end
```

And outputs as such:

```
$r<ParaStyle:-body copy>$line11
```

The output I see at the end of it all is:

**${name1}**

I want the value of name1 to be put into the stylization text, instead of the name of the variable.  This seems to be how the Velocity specs tell me to do this.  ( [reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/user-guide.html#String%20Concatenation) )What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `"<CharStyle:-bold black>$name1<CharStyle:>"`, i.e. without the curly braces?

Comment: That gives me $name1 instead of ${name1} as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${name1}` will evaluate to the literal string `"${name1}"` if `name1` is null. So it looks to me like `name1` is null. You might also want to change your #if condition to `#if ($name1)`, which will evaluate to `false` if `name1` is null.

Comment: That's exactly the problem.  Thank you very much.